# How 3D images are made

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

I am a beginner level Illustrator user. I have an assignment to create a cartoon image like this:

[image]

[image]

How can I create lively cartoon images with Illustrator?

Comment: Any tool that can produce an image will work.

Comment: any source, tutorial?

Comment: @Daniel any resource or effort on your part? (What have you already tried? Where are you having trouble? This is *your* assignment, after all)

Comment: It wouldnt really help you to pick randomly one method over another. You need to somehow sow what you know how to do and deconstruct the actual problem. Its one thing to ask how to set up a perspective grid another totally to ask the entire way from nothing to mastery.

Comment: what i meant was whether there's any specialized software for that which i am missing or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ilustrator is not the best tool for this. Not at all.

If you do know how to paint, use a paint program.

Photoshop, CorelPainter, Sai even Paint. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGOLqU8AZpo and a ton of programs, but depends on the artist skill.

If you know how to paint with phisical emdiums, do that and take a photo after.

Or try a direct 3D modeling and rendering program. Maya, Cinema 4D, Blender, 3Dstudio.

There are some other kind of 3D programs, some other are to sculpt, like Zbrush and sculpturis.

Comment: I dont think a 3D application is a good idea. I mean yes you can do this with one, but you have atleast a 6 month learning curve.

Comment: @joojaa: aren't you then implying that training to do the same with Illustrator will take significantly less than 6 months?

Comment: @RadLexus yes i am.

Comment: Not entirely. If you put specific objetives, you can do a decent project in a week, if you have dedication and some skils... and talent.

Comment: Maybe but not commercial quality for a first time 3D user in a week.